# Is there a java1.8.jj for javacc?

Tags: java, javacc

I was using ant to build some files and I was going through javacc. I found that javacc 6.0 has some .jj files for java 1.5 and 1.6, does anyone know if it was updated with a java1.8.jj file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JavaParser](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser) is a mature parser for Java which supports Java 8 (and we are starting working on Java 9).

It is based on JavaCC, so it contains a JavaCC grammar for Java 8. Depending on what you need to do you could use the whole project or just adapt the grammar to your need.

JavaParser is released under Apache License 2.0 and LGPL: you can choose under which terms to use it.

Source: I am a contributor to JavaParser

Answer (score 2):

Please see [javaparser-core/java_1_8.jj](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser/blob/master/javaparser-core/src/main/javacc/java_1_8.jj).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other comments: the [grammar](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser/blob/master/javaparser-core/src/main/javacc/java.jj) in the JavaParser project has been "enhanced" with Java code for several nasty situations and it is not recommended to use it without the rest of the library.